# How come data is fetched with ActivatedRoute.snapshot.data['']?

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-components

I just started learning Angular, and I saw this piece of code:

```
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {

  private Products: Product[];


  constructor(private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) 
  {
   
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.Products = this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['Products'];
  }

}
```

And it's obvious someone is getting data using this code:

```
this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['Products'];
```

How come services are not used to get data? And I'm wondering where this data are coming from then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this._activatedRoute.snapshot.data['Products'];` this code is not getting the data from the database and you got confused by that.

**It is the data that you sent while navigationg through routes**

During a navigation, after redirects have been applied, **the router creates a `RouterStateSnapshot`**

**So what is a `RouteStateSnapshot:`**

**Official Definition:**

> Contains the information about a route associated with a component
>   loaded in an outlet at a particular moment in time.
>   ActivatedRouteSnapshot can also be used to traverse the router state
>   tree.

**Little more explanation:**

> RouteStateSnapshot is an immutable data structure representing the
>   state of the router at a particular moment in time. Any time a
>   component is added or removed or parameter is updated, a new snapshot
>   is created.

Here is the actual code of that `snapshot`

```
interface RouterStateSnapshot {
  root: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
}

interface ActivatedRouteSnapshot {
  url: UrlSegment[];
  params: {[name:string]:string};
  data: {[name:string]:any};

  queryParams: {[name:string]:string};
  fragment: string;

  root: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
  parent: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
  firstchild: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
  children: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[];
}
```

It contains the details of `URL`, `component`, `data`, `params` etc

**Let us look into an example and route configuration:**

```
[
  {
    path: ':folder',
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ConversationsCmp
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        component: ConversationCmp,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'messages',
            component: MessagesCmp
          },
          {
            path: 'messages/:id',
            component: MessageCmp,
            resolve: {
              message: MessageResolver
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

When we are navigating to `/inbox/10/messages/11`, the router will look at the `URL` and will construct the following `RouterStateSnapshot`:

```
component: MessageCmp
url: [‘messages’, ‘11’]
params: {id: ’10‘}
data: {}
```

So, the `product data` you are thinking may come from this `route data`

[This is the refered documentation](https://vsavkin.com/angular-router-understanding-router-state-7b5b95a12eab)

[Here is the documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRouteSnapshot)